# How can I display properties/attributes of an object in an editor?

Tags: c++, architecture, imgui

I'm learning how to make a game engine using SDL and OpenGL and I'm using imgui for the engine editor UI and I'm trying to make a properties panel that displays the properties of the selected object. The code I currently have works although it's extremely basic and I'm realizing that it'll probably become very repetitive the more I add so I'd like to know what I could do to improve.

So I have a base GameElement class and a few test classes that derive from it and I use a `GetProperties` function to get the values I want to be displayed for the imgui panel

```
        std::vector<Section> GetProperties() override {
            std::vector<Section> sections;

            // Data 
            Section dataSection("Data");
            dataSection.AddProperty(new StringProperty("Name", name));
            dataSection.AddProperty(new BoolProperty("Archivable", archivable));
            sections.push_back(dataSection);

            // Appearance
            Section appearanceSection("Appearance");
            appearanceSection.AddProperty(new Vector3Property("BackgroundColor3", someVector));
            sections.push_back(appearanceSection);

            return sections;
        }
```

And then in my Editor class I have this which displays the imgui window

```
    void Editor::Properties() {
        ImGui::Begin("Properties");

        if (selectedElement) {
            auto sections = selectedElement->GetProperties();
            for (auto& section : sections) {
                section.Render();
            }
        }

        ImGui::End();
    }
```

But yeah the more elements I add and the more properties I start to add to them I'll probably end up with a lot of duplicate code, but since not every element is the same I can't just like make a base class so I'm not sure what I can do here.